# CSS !important rule use, specificity

Tags: css, css-specificity

I am writing a bunch of PHP classes which will be used to create a Wordpress plugin, but can also be used in any other environment. After testing my script by itself, all seems well, but when I created a WP plugin for it, there were CSS conflicts that I had foreseen. I initially planned on using specificity to solve these, but it can't always be done. This is in the default WP theme:

```
#content tr td {
    border-top: 1px solid #E7E7E7;
    padding: 6px 24px;
}
```

If I try to specify a td to have no padding, it won't work unless I add an ID to my table, rather than a class. I have seen popular plugins that implemented the !important rule on every single CSS property rather than using an ID for specificity. Which is best? I know the !important rule should be used sparingly, but adding an ID to my table seems to go against semantics, since there will be multiple instances of this table with the same ID:

> The ID attribute of a document
>   language allows authors to assign an
>   identifier to one element instance in
>   the document tree.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#id-selectors

**EDIT:**
An alternative may also be to wrap everything in a div with an ID, but if there exists a rule #content #main td or similar, it will still dominate over my #someid td. Also, as discussed below, it is not valid to have two elements sharing the same ID, although it may "work".

Comment: Why not use a `class` then? Assuming `#content` is the container element that is a parent of your table, `#content .mytables tr td` will still be more specific than the original selector

Comment: Yes that would also work, but I don't want to add any further restrictions on it, because the PHP classes can work with any PHP environment and I don't want to specify a WP specific #content ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I've said in the comments, you can include the `#content` rule in your selector together with a class to override the original styles *if* `#content` is the wrapper element (and it should be, since if is added to all table elements than there won't be any way of adding more than one table to WordPress posts, which would be... weird).

Anyway, if you *have* to choose between adding `id`s to multiple elements, and using `!important` on your properties, I would use `!important` for the simple reason that while `!important` may make your stylesheets unmaintainable, adding multiple `id`s may also break any JavaScript used on the page, and there's no guarantee that the id selector implementation in all browsers can accommodate multiple elements with the same `id`, so the consequences are more severe.

Basically, choosing between one highly-unrecommanded-but-otherwise-valid practise and invalid, undefined behavior.

Comment: I knew conflicts may exist with several instances of the plugin, so I decided to use a unique ID for each root DIV for my plugin, that way I know that they are separate instances. But I agree that having two elements with the same IDs is a bit weird. So I suppose that adding !important rules may be the only way to ensure that nothing (almost) can break my CSS rules...

Comment: @AramKocharyan It's not just 'a little weird', it's actually invalid HTML. And with invalid HTML browsers break in weird and wonderful ways, so do keep that in mind if you want to do this. Another way would be to use two selectors here: `.mytables, #content .mytable`, the more specific one for WP and the less specific one for everybody else

Comment: I think that suggestion is far more viable than using the !importort rule, unless there is no other way. I'll try that out, cheers!